# Remote desktop is not working anymore after changing Network access in Local Policy, Security Options

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, remote-desktop, network-share

I've followed the instruction in [this post](https://geekdecoder.com/windows-server-2008-access-the-shared-folder-without-giving-the-username-and-password/) and changed some settings on the server, restarted the server and now I can't do remote desktop anymore.

I think the culprits are the last three things that I have done from that instruction. i.e., (i) Accounts: Guest account status Enabled,
(ii) Network access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users Enabled, and
(iii) Network access: Sharing and Security model for local accounts – set to Guestonly – local users authenticate as guest.

I've contacted the host provider to see if they can physically log-in and rollback these changes. In the meanwhile, is there anything that I can do?